# What is a porcupine driver (credits)?

Tags: terminology, rambo-last-blood

I just watched *[Rambo: Last Blood](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1206885/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_cl_sm#:%7E:text=Konstantin%20Vasilev,porcupine%20technician)*, and in the credits there was a listing for a

> **Porcupine Driver**: *Jorge Julio Gomez*
>
> [image]

It was a couple of names before the [*honeywagon driver*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeywagon_(vehicle)), which I know sucks the crap out of portapotties, but **what the heck is a Porcupine Driver?**

Comment: Are there porcupines in the film? I’m wondering if driver=wrangler.

Comment: Additionally, a porcupine is also the name of a type of mobile artillery unit, like a howitzer built into a tank; having not seen the film does such a vehicle feature?

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional your option sounds more plausible than mine, given it’s a Rambo film.

Comment: What is the name of the person credited?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'porcupine' is a camera rig that allows for 360-degree filming at speed.

> On the film London Has Fallen (2016), Nu Boyana came up came up with a
> device they call the ‘porcupine rig’. It’s a Mini Cooper convertible
> with a 360-degree Red camera array in the back. I think there were ten
> Red cameras that collectively shoot a 360-degree plate. So this gave
> us the freedom to shoot with any lens on the stage without having to
> match to the plate.
>
> Several weeks after the stage work the Visual Effects Team headed out
> with the porcupine rig and shot the plates. The interior car scenes
> where Reynolds and Jackson travel at night from the Coventry Safe
> House to the Forested Road were all shot on stage in Sofia. Weeks
> later the porcupine rig went out into Bulgarian farmland at dusk, and
> in the early evening, to shoot the plates. It worked beautifully.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

The 'Porcupine' has also been used in a range of other films including *[Rambo: Last Blood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rambo:_Last_Blood)*, [*Expend4bles*](https://www.metacritic.com/movie/expend4bles/credits/) and *[Hitman's Wife's Bodyguard](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8385148/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_cl_sm)*.

The 'Porcupine Driver' is the guy who drives the porcupine.

Comment: and the guy next to him is the porcupine technician, also found in the credits -  https://acmag.com.au/2017/09/01/the-hitmans-bodyguard/ -

Comment: That is absolutely wild. And with that many Red cameras, probably more expensive than a gold plated mini cooper.